# Possible to calculate the squared perimeter of a 2d triangle without square-root calls?

Tags: geometry

For a more efficient perimeter calculation *

Is it possible to avoid 3x length calculations (therefor square-root calls)
when calculating a 2D triangles *squared* perimeter?

To be clear, by squared perimeter I mean the actual perimeter multiplied by it's self. The square-root of this value would be the actual perimeter.

Just as the squared length is often used for comparisons.

---

*Efficient with floating point on todays typical CPU's*

Comment: What is squared perimeter? `a^2+b^2+c^2 <> (a+b+c)^2`

Comment: Updated question, hope its more clear.

Comment: It is right part of my inequality. Seems there is no simple way to get it. But why do you need perimeter?

Comment: Asking because of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46212151 but don't think its especially relevant since this is a primitive operation.

Comment: You could  try to use sum of length squares (left part) as estimation.

Comment: Even as an estimation, its not really useful, it varies too much based on its scale.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to get `(a+b+c)^2` value for triangle.

But seems that using perimeter in linked topic is not the best way.

Note  also that using Heron formula is not wise. Cross-product is much simpler and faster.

Moreover, you need some criteria of triangle elongation. Why not use comparison of values like this:

```
E = Max(AB^2, AC^2, BC^2) / CrossProduct(AB,AC)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but probably best to reply to the other question on that page.